Error pasarela de MP modo sandbox
hace unos dias que vengo teniendo este error al tratar de hacer un simulacion de pago .. primero me dejaba ingresar datos de la tarjeta pero al hacer el pago salia que hubo un error ahora intente de nuevo y ya ni siquiera puedo ingresar nada solo me aparece lo siguiente
https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/227917/164728741-6974c3e1-4682-4fa4-b109-2c6c9aa748d8.png
es el mismo error que surge a mi... cabe aclarar que estos dias estuve usando la pasarela de pago normalmente pero derrepente empezo a fallar..

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! El sitio tiene un servidor de imagenes, pero mas alla de eso, los errores deben ir como texto y con el codigo que facilite ver que esta pasando.. si no, es a ciegas.. igual, deberias consultarlo con MP, no?

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
